# как получит values в redux-form на втором шаге при успешной отправке формы?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

здравствуйте! Подскажите. Использую redux-form и имею двухшаговую форму. Мне нужно на втором шаге рендерить значение инпута, введенное на первом шаге. Дело в том, что values в redux-form зачищаются при успешной отправке формы, и я не могу получить их на втором шаге. Можно записывать в стор отдельно это значение на первом шаге, но не хотелось бы дублировать данные.

Как быть в этом случае?

Answer (score 0):

Исходя  из примера на оф сайте https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/examples/wizard/ каждый шаг формы должен быть оформлен вот так, чтобы данные сохранялись в течение всех шагов:

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'wizard', // <------ same form name
  destroyOnUnmount: false, // <------ preserve form data
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true, // <------ unregister fields on unmount
  validate
})(WizardFormFirstPage)
```